# Is there an explicit construction of an embedding of Severi Brauer varieties $B(A)\times_k B(A')\hookrightarrow B(A\otimes_k A')$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This question arose from a note on Galois descent. If $A$ is a central simple algebra over a field $k$, let $B(A)$ be its Severi Brauer variety. There is always at least a morphism $$B(A)\times_k B(A')\to B(A\otimes_k A').$$

I am wondering, is there an explicit description/construction of a closed embedding $B(A)\times_k B(A')\hookrightarrow B(A\otimes_k A')$?

Answer (score 2):

Sure. If I'm understanding the question correctly, this is just a twisted form of the standard Segre embedding, defined by taking a pair of right ideals $I$, $J$, to their tensor product $I \otimes J$.